# Attributes in where condition

Tags: xquery

Lets say this is the XML file I have.

```
<bookstore>
 <book year="1994">
  <title>blah</title>
  <price>66</price>
 </book>
 <book year="1998">
  <title>blahblah</title>
  <price>99</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

How do I select all books where the year attribute is `<1995` and price is `<70`.

This is what I have:

```
for $x in doc("bkstr.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price<70 and ??
return $x
```

How do i check the value of the year attribute?

Comment: Please make sure to post both valid code and example input. You've been missing `in` in the `for`-loop and the slash in closing `</bookstore>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are addressed by using `@`.

```
for $x in doc("bkstr.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price<70 and $x/@year<1995
return $x
```

You can also use the much shorter equivalent

```
doc("bkstr.xml")/bookstore/book[price<70 and @year<1995]
```